# What are the benefits and the commands to use the new Bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

I have been using Rails for a couple years now and took a break away for a few months and just found myself back on a Rails application. The only problem is I don't know how to use bundler. I've been doing research and I find the command

```
bundle install
```

but what others are there and does this actually install the gems locally or just for the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'bundle install' installs the required gems (specified in Gemfile) on the system.

if you want to know more options, take a look here: http://gembundler.com/rails3.html

bundler helps you to manage dependecies required, you can also 'lock' gems, so your app will use only the specified gems.

you can also 'cache' the required gems with 'bundle package', they'll be compressed in vendor/cache, then when you launch 'bunlde install' it will take the cached gems (think something like freezeing gems)